# Accessing label text using accessibility identifiers

Tags: javascript, ios, ios-ui-automation, uiaccessibility

I have added an accessibility identifier to a label so that I can use it in my UIAutomation javascript files. How do I access the text on the label using accessibility identifier?

Suppose "aLabel" is the accessibility identifier and my javascript function to access the text on that label is:

```
appLabelValue:function()
{
return this.getElement('aLabel').value();
}
```

I even tried replacing .value() with .text() in the above method but I am getting same error for both i.e. undefined is not a function.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You access the values of `UIElements` by using `name()`
try this

```
appLabelValue:function()
{
return this.getElement('aLabel').name();
}
```

Comment: Tried that... I am getting the accessibilityIdentifier string back i.e. aLabel. What I want is suppose the label has a text say "MyLabel" and label's accessibility identifier is "aLabel", then using "aLabel", I want to get or access "MyLabel" text.